# Json.Net - performant deserialization onto interface based data structure?

Tags: c#, json, interface, tree, json.net

As soon as I don't have *only* concrete types in the data structures I deserialize a HUGE json tree structure into, it starts using enormous amounts of memory, but its memory footprint stays relatively slim when deserializing into entirely concrete types… is there an elegant workaround for this?

The json I get is generated elsewhere, so I have no influence as to the format I get it in (it's a tree structure, similar to the code example below if it were serialized to json directly), and in the worst case about 250-300MB of it. 
My data structure for mapping it used to look somewhat like the following example (structs in some places, though)

```
public class Node : INode
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NodeTypeConverter<IInnerNode, InnerNodeType1>))]
    public List<INodeInner> InnerNodes { get; set; }
}

public class InnerNodeNodeType1 : INode
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NodeTypeConverter<IInnerNode, InnerNodeType2>))]
    public List<INodeInner> InnerNodes { get; set; }

    // some other properties
}

public class InnerNodeNodeType2 : INode
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NodeTypeConverter<IInnerNode, InnerNodeType3>))]
    public List<INodeInner> InnerNodes { get; set; }

    // some even different properties
}

…
```

however, I did not find a way to map this without bringing the PC it runs on to its knees, especially memory-wise (apart from that, in some places with `List<interface>` I didn't even get json.Net to use the converter, it threw an error `Could not create an instance of type {type}. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.` before even checking the converter class…).

So now, I changed it to all-concrete types/Lists of concrete type instances instead of the interfaces plus a converter, and it runs with MUCH less of a memory footprint (orders of magnitude!). But it's inelegant, because this way, I can't reuse most of the classes for different kinds of trees I'll have to use in other places of the program, which are similar, but subtly different.

Is there an elegant solution for this?

PS: Thanks for reading this far! This question might not be perfectly posed and/or contain all and any type of info you might need to suggest a solution. I've found, however, that anytime I tried to cover all bases and anticipate all further questions, I got no responses *at all*, so that's my attempt to ask differently this time… :P

Comment: Can you share your code for `NodeTypeConverter<TInterface, TConcrete>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide a concrete example of your problem, but you did write *I changed it to all-concrete types/Lists of concrete type instances instead of the interfaces plus a converter, and it runs with MUCH less of a memory footprint (orders of magnitude!)*.  It sounds as though you must be loading large chunks of JSON into memory in some intermediate representation, such as a `string` for the entire JSON or a `JArray` for the complete contents of your `public List<INodeInner> InnerNodes` arrays.  After that you are converting the intermediate representation(s) into your final objects.

What you need to do is to avoid loading any intermediate representations, or if you must do so, load only the smallest possible JSON chunk at once.  The following is an example implementation:

```
public interface INode
{
    List<INodeInner> InnerNodes { get; set; }
}

public interface INodeInner : INode
{
}

public class Node : INode
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(InterfaceToConcreteConverter<INodeInner, InnerNodeNodeType1>))]
    public List<INodeInner> InnerNodes { get; set; }
}

public class InnerNodeNodeType1 : INodeInner
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(InterfaceToConcreteConverter<INodeInner, InnerNodeNodeType2>))]
    public List<INodeInner> InnerNodes { get; set; }

    // some other properties
    public int Type1Property { get; set; }
}

public class InnerNodeNodeType2 : INodeInner
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(InterfaceToConcreteConverter<INodeInner, InnerNodeNodeType3>))]
    public List<INodeInner> InnerNodes { get; set; }

    // some even different properties
    public int Type2Property { get; set; }
}

public class InnerNodeNodeType3 : INodeInner
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(InterfaceToConcreteConverter<INodeInner, InnerNodeNodeType3>))]
    public List<INodeInner> InnerNodes { get; set; }

    // some even different properties
    public int Type3Property { get; set; }
}

public class InterfaceToConcreteConverter<TInterface, TConcrete> : JsonConverter where TConcrete : TInterface
{
    public InterfaceToConcreteConverter()
    {
        // TConcrete should be a subtype of an abstract type, or an implementation of an interface.  If they
        // are identical an infinite recursion could result, so throw an exception.
        if (typeof(TInterface) == typeof(TConcrete))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("typeof({0}) == typeof({1})", typeof(TInterface), typeof(TConcrete)));
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(TInterface);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(TConcrete));
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then, to load:

```
Node root;
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    // Whatever settings you need.
};
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
using (var textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
{
    root = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Deserialize<Node>(reader);
}
```

Notes:

1. Rather than writing a converter for the entire `List<INodeInner> InnerNodes` and applying it with `[JsonConverter(typeof(NodeTypeConverter<IInnerNode, InnerNodeType1>))]`, I created a converter for each list item and apply it by setting [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm):

   ```
   [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(InterfaceToConcreteConverter<INodeInner, InnerNodeNodeType1>))]
   public List<INodeInner> InnerNodes { get; set; }
   ```

   Thus simplifies the converter and guarantees that, if the converter needs to preload the JSON into an intermediate `JToken`, only one list item is preloaded and converted at once.
2. Since, in your example, the type of `INodeInner` is fixed for each type of `INode`, it isn't even necessary to preload individual list items.  Instead, in [`JsonConverter.ReadJson()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm), deserialize directly from the incoming `JsonReader` using the correct concrete type:

   ```
   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
       return serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(TConcrete));
   }
   ```
3. As explained in [Newtonsoft Performance Tips: Optimize Memory Usage](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm), when deserializing a large JSON file, deserialize directly from a stream:

   ```
   using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
   using (var textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
   using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
   {
       root = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Deserialize<Node>(reader);
   }
   ```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bdnLtM) showing this working.