# C# Newtonsoft: how do deserialize interface containing interface containing interface, without Json attributes

Tags: c#, interface, nested, json.net, deserialization

I have the following code which breaks at the last line with exception "Could not create an instance of type DeserializeInterfaces.IC".  How can I deserialize without using any attributes like:

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(ConcreteConverter<C>))]`
```

I can't use the attributes because the interfaces are in a different project and I can't have a circular dependency of the interfaces on the concrete classes.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace DeserializeInterfaces
{
  public class CustomInterfaceConverter : JsonConverter
  {
    public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType )
    {
      bool convertible = typeof( IB ).IsAssignableFrom( objectType )
                         || typeof( IC ).IsAssignableFrom( objectType );

      return convertible;
    }

    public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
      JObject jsonObject = JObject.Load( reader );
          
      if (objectType.Name == "IB")
      {
        B retVal = jsonObject.ToObject<B>();
        return retVal;
      }
      if (objectType.Name == "IC")
      {
        C retVal = jsonObject.ToObject<C>();
        return retVal;
      }
      // Handle other cases or return a default implementation
      return null;
    }
    public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }

  public interface IA
  {
    IB b { get; set; }
  }

  public class A : IA
  {
    public A() { }

    public IB b { get; set; }
  }

  public interface IB
  {
    IC c { get; set; }
  }


  public class B : IB
  {
    public B() { }

    public B( IC pC )
    {
      c = pC;
    }

    public IC c { get; set; }
  }

  public interface IC
  {
    int v { get; set; }
  }

  public class C : IC
  {
    public C() { }

    public C( int pV )
    {
      v = pV;
    }

    public int v { get; set; }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      CustomInterfaceConverter jsonConverter = new CustomInterfaceConverter();
      IA a = new A();
      a.b = new B();
      a.b.c = new C();
      a.b.c.v = 1;
      string aSer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( a );

      A aDeser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>( aSer, jsonConverter );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You certainly will not get any help without posting your json string

Comment: How does this differ from the question you asked 3 hours previously?  [C# Newtonsoft: How to deserialize an interface containing an interface, without Json attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77244256/3744182).

Comment: @Serge the code indeed generates the JSON string... Could you please clarify why do you think it is not enough?

Comment: That question was for an interface containing interface.  This is interface containing interface containing interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `IA` should always be deserialized as `A`, `IB` as `B` and `IC` as `C`, you may use three instances of `InterfaceToConcreteConverter<TInterface, TConcrete>` to deserialize your JSON, one for each interface, where the converter is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45008406/3744182) to *[Json.Net - performant deserialization onto interface based data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44881562/3744182)*:

```
public class InterfaceToConcreteConverter<TInterface, TConcrete> : JsonConverter where TConcrete : TInterface
{
    static InterfaceToConcreteConverter()
    {
        // TConcrete should be a subtype of an abstract type, or an implementation of an interface.  If they
        // are identical an infinite recursion could result, so throw an exception.
        if (typeof(TInterface) == typeof(TConcrete))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("typeof({0}) == typeof({1})", typeof(TInterface), typeof(TConcrete)));
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) =>objectType == typeof(TInterface);
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(TConcrete));
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

With this converter, your serialization code would look like:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new InterfaceToConcreteConverter<IA, A>(), 
                  new InterfaceToConcreteConverter<IB, B>(),
                  new InterfaceToConcreteConverter<IC, C>(),}
};

string aSer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( a, settings );

A aDeser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>( aSer, settings );
```

Notes:

- This answer depends on the fact that each interface has one and only one concrete implementation. If this is not correct, you will need to use some sort of previously serialized type identifier to determine the concrete type.
- [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) is your friend here.  It's much easier to create a generic interface-to-concrete converter and instantiate three instances than create some omnibus converter for all interfaces.

  If you have many different places where you need to serialize or deserialize using the converters, you could create static default settings for projectwide use:

  ```
  public static class JsonExtensions
  {
      public static JsonSerializerSettings DefaultSettings { get; } =
          new JsonSerializerSettings
          {
              Converters = { new InterfaceToConcreteConverter<IA, A>(), 
                            new InterfaceToConcreteConverter<IB, B>(),
                            new InterfaceToConcreteConverter<IC, C>(),}
          };
  }

  A aDeser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>( aSer, JsonExtensions.DefaultSettings );
  ```
- By returning `false` from [`CanWrite`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) default serialization will be used when writing.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kyccfc).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass serializer to all your `ToObject` calls so it can recursively call your converter (instead of using default):

```
B retVal = jsonObject.ToObject<B>(serializer);
```

Comment: I tried that, but got infinite recursion into the JsonConverter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attributes on class properties (not interfaces). And since this converter doesn't use any interfaces, it doesnt need each interface has one and only one concrete implementation (as @dbc solution needs)

```
A aDeser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(aSer);

public class CustomInterfaceConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken o = JToken.Load(reader);
        return o.ToObject(Type.GetType((string)o["TypeName"]));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(AType);
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
}
```

classes

```
public abstract class AType
{
    public string TypeName
    {
        get { return this.GetType().Name; }
    }
}

public class A : AType, IA
{
    public A() { }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomInterfaceConverter))]
    public IB b { get; set; }
}
public class B : AType, IB
{
    public B() { }

    public B(IC pC)
    {
        c = pC;
    }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomInterfaceConverter))]
    public IC c { get; set; }
}
public class C : AType, IC
{
    public C() { }

    public C(int pV)
    {
        v = pV;
    }

    public int v { get; set; }
}
```